# Velocity at a place for fluid with a given pressure gradient?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

In a spherical coordinate system, the origin is a sink with fluid extending to infinite distance.
The pressure gradient generated in the fluid is:

$$\nabla P \alpha \frac{1}{r^2}$$

where $r$ is the distance measured from origin.

I need to calculate square of velocity of a fluid element at any given point. I am getting $v^2 \alpha \frac{1}{r}$ but the answer is $v^2 \alpha \frac{1}{r^2}$.

I know I need to integrate the relation:

$$v \frac{dv}{dr} = \frac{1}{\rho} \nabla P$$

But integrating will yield $v^2 \alpha \frac{1}{r}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using $\alpha$ in place of $\propto$ (`propto`)? It

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer should be
$$v \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt r}.$$
Indeed, if we assume a purely radial, steady, incompressible, inviscid flow, then the Navier-Stokes equation along the radial coordinate reduces to the form you used:
$$v\frac{dv}{dr} = - \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dP}{dr} \propto -\frac{1}{r^2}.$$
But
$$v\frac{dv}{dr} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{dv^2}{dr},$$
Then we have
$$\frac{dv^2}{dr} \propto -\frac{1}{r^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad v^2 \propto \frac{1}{r} \quad \Rightarrow \quad v \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt r}.$$

One can also arrive at the same solution without using the radial and steady flow assumptions, and that's by exploiting the analogy to gravitational force. The pressure gradient
$$\frac{dP}{dr} \propto -\frac{1}{r^2}$$
is equivalent to a gravitational field as given by Newton's law. Thus, if pressure is the only force acting on the fluid element, one can imagine an associated potential energy which is proportional to $-\frac{1}{r}$. Conservation of energy then implies that kinetic energy is proportional to $\frac{1}{r}$, and thus
$$v^2 \propto \frac{1}{r} \quad \Rightarrow \quad v \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt r}.$$

Comment: Oh sorry, the quantity to be found is $v^2$. I will fix it in the question.

Comment: OK, so your answer is correct